# How to enable Survival Mode in Fallout 1.4 Patch?

Tags: fallout-4

I switched the game difficulty to `Survival` however I still can fast travel and the ammo remains weightless. (PS4)

Comment: I'm torn on closing this or not. I'm going to vote to leave it open, since they're basically asking if a feature is in a specific patch, and that patch *has* been released, even though the feature hasn't been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survival mode is not out yet. You can select the difficulty, but many of the features linked to the mode are not included in the game yet.

> A new patch is making its way to consoles by end of this week, and many expect that the next patch after this one will finally include the new survival mode content.

Source : [Gamerant](http://gamerant.com/fallout-4-survival-mode-sleep-mod-124/)

Answer (score 0):

As Isuka said, `Survival Mode` as you want to play it has not been released, and as of the date of my answer, no news about it's release date has been revealed.

The survival mode difficulty that came with the game and the `Survival Mode` update are two completely different things.

The current survival mode difficulty only reduces the amount of damage you do to enemies and also reduces the effect of AID items (stimpaks, purified water etc... I believe). Ammo is weightless as it is in lower difficulties.

By the way, `Survival Mode` beta is to be released on Steam for PC before it reaches consoles.